# Cannot Assign Width With Respect To Outermost Container

Tags: css

In the snippet below, I want to assign a max-width of %10 to the span so that it will take up maximum %10 of the outer-most container div, which is 100% of the body width actually.

But I guess because the width of the container is determined by the content, it seems to be 10% of the width of a span which would contain the unrestricted text.

How can I get the desired output?

jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/68ha60p6/

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  }
```

```html
<div style="float:right; height:100%;padding-right:1%"> 
<button style="display:inline-block; height:70%;background-color:green; color:white;border:none; padding:0;">
<span style="display:inline-block; max-width:10%; text-overflow:ellipses;overflow:hidden; max-height:100%;text-align:center;white-space:no-wrap;">John John</span>
</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not determined by content. Percentage dimensions are calculated based on the size of the immediately containing parent. In this case, the immediately containing parent of your span is your button, so your span is being set to 10% of that.

Comment: @Ryan How is the width of the button determined?

Comment: Most browsers have a fallback default styling that will render a blank button in he absence of anything specific, but it can vary by browser. A button will also stretch if its contents require it. In this case, you have no styling, and he contents are set specifically to 10% of the button width, so you're just getting the browser default. If you're looking for the span to be 10% of the width of the div that the button is in, you might try just moving the span so it sits outside the button.

Answer (score 0):

For the span's width, use `max-width:10vw;` instead of `max-width:10%;`

`1vw` is equal to 1% of the viewport (browser window) width.

Comment: I tried that already but since there is a min-width, max-width limitation on the body, giving percentages relative to the viewport does not work as expected since body is not always %100 of the viewport. I can use pixels but I am looking for a way to avoid using pixels in favor of responsive design.

Comment: Do you really need a span inside the button, or you can put all your styles on the button itself and make that 10% of its parent?